# AndroidStudio cannot get any Library from the Internet

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidstudio-settings

When I use AndroidStudio ,I cannot get any Library from the Internet, just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjrtf.png)

this is My Gradle [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Z5f.png)

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What have you tried? What errors did you see? Have it worked before?

Answer (score 0):

You can search dependencies at [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) first, and then copy the gradle dependency to your grade file, instead of search dependencies in Android studio.
Fot example, search GSON:

[Figure : search GSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sLCa.png)

and paste dependency to your gradle script:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    ...
}
...
```